# Get custom html attribute values in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am using Angular 2 to build my application. This is my code so far:

**Template**

```
<select class="form-control input-xs" [(ngModel)]="filter.coordinatorId" name="coordinatorId" (ngModelChange)="onCoordinatorChange($event)">                                                              
    <option *ngFor="let coordinator of coordinators; let i = index" [value]="coordinator.id" [selected]="i==0">{{coordinator.name}}</option>                                    
</select>
```

**Component**

```
onCoordinatorChange(coordinatorId: number){
        alert(coordinatorId);
        //business logic
    }
```

As you can see, I set `[value]="coordinator.id"` in `option` so I am getting `coordinator.id` value in alert, and if I change it to `coordinator.name` then I will get that value. But here I want to get multiple values like `coordinator.id`,`coordinator.name`,`coordinator.department` etc. So one solution could be using comma separated but that will be ugly and hard to maintain if other parameters come. Do I have any other option to write my function something like:

```
onCoordinatorChange(coordinatorId: number, name: string, department: string){
            alert(coordinatorId);
            //business logic
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]` and just set whole object as a value, that way you will pass entire object and you will have access to all its attributes:

```
<select class="form-control input-xs" [(ngModel)]="filter.coordinator" name="coordinatorId" (ngModelChange)="onCoordinatorChange($event)">                                                              
    <option *ngFor="let coordinator of coordinators; let i = index" [ngValue]="coordinator" [selected]="i==0">{{coordinator.name}}</option>                                    
</select>
```

Comment: Both awesome answers came in almost no time, +1. Confused what to accept ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]` and pass the `coordinator` instead of `coordinator.id`

```
[ngValue]="coordinator"
```

This would need to be changed to though

```
[(ngModel)]="filter.coordinator"
```

Comment: Both awesome answers came in almost no time, +1. Confused what to accept ;)

Comment: Accept Stefans.  . . . . .

Comment: Really funny situation, haha! Write post on stackoverflow meta and ask for option to accept two answers. ;-)

Comment: Way to much hassle. I'm not suffering from lack of reps, so no worries ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer haha.. yeah you should start answering bounty questions only :D